# Product-topology of discrete $\{ 0, 1 \}$ spaces

Tags: general-topology

I was thinking about the following: Take the product $\prod_{i \in I} \{ 0, 1 \}$ for each $\{ 0, 1 \}$ being discrete. Is the product-topology also the discrete topology?

I'd say intuitively "no", but a single-point is closed as a product of $T_1$-spaces is again $T_1$. Then its complement is also a point, therefore closed. Hence every point is open, and we get that $\prod_{i \in I} \{ 0, 1 \}$ is discrete. Is my reasoning correct, or did I not see an important point?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The product topology is discrete if and only if $I$ is finite. If $I$ is countably infinite, the product is homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

The complement of a singleton is not a singleton unless $I$ is a one-point set. If $I$ has at least two elements, then $\prod_{i\in I}\{0,1\}$ has at least $2^2=4$ elements, so the complement of a singleton has at least three elements. More important, if $I$ is infinite, so is $\prod_{i\in I}\{0,1\}$ (indeed, it’s uncountable), so the complement of a singleton is infinite and by no means has to be closed.

Comment: Just to be sure that I've understood: Isn't the complement of $\{ 0 \} \times \{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times \cdots$ equal to $\{ 1 \} \times \{ 0 \} \times \{ 1 \} \times \cdots$?

Comment: @Steven: No, it isn’t. Draw a picture of $\{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$. Then mark in $\{0\}\times\{1\}$ and $\{1\}\times\{0\}$, and you’ll see that they don’t exhaust the product: they’re missing the points $\langle 0,0\rangle$ and $\langle 1,1\rangle$.

Comment: Aw, silly me! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Steven: You’re welcome!